# Unable to run multiple applications on one PC

Tags: c#, wpf, udpclient

I have 3 WPF applications that were running on 3 separate PCs and are communicating using UDP with each other. When I run all them on one PC they cannot share the Port on which they communicate and so crash. Is there a way in which these applications communicate with each other on the same PC?

Comment: They are using the same port ... change the port

Comment: I guess, for the communication to be possible, they should communicate on same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they shouldn't have the same port number that is forbidden, the idea behind the port number is to differentiate between the processes, and you said you have three apps that's mean you have three processes, each process should have separate port number, and when you try to send the data between the processes talk them by they port numbers and the local ip, assume you have port 1111 for the first app and 2222 for the second app, if you want to send data from the first to the second use the local ip and 2222 for the port, and vise versa.

your problem is when the first app open he tell the windows i will listen to this port any package came to you in that number send it to me, when the second app open he tell the windows the same thing windows will reply by exception no there is another app take that port.